# Импортировать HTML код из другого файла в код

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли с помощью `JS` импортировать код(несколько `<div>`) хранящийся в другом `HTML` файле и вставить его в тег в основном коде? Если да, то какие функции посоветуете использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам придется сделать запрос по url и результат запроса вставить в html.

Вариант [без jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes)

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'x.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;
    if (this.status!==200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
    document.getElementById('y').innerHTML= this.responseText;
};
xhr.send();
```

Вариант [с jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486590/get-html-code-of-a-local-html-file-in-javascript)

```
$(function() {
    $('#loadContent').load('page1.html');
});
```